# Combinatorics - drawing two cards at random from a deck of $52$ cards.

Tags: probability

Two cards are randomly drawn from a deck of $52$ playing cards.

Find the probability that both cards will be greater than $3$ and less than $8$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you guys. ITs actually my first time using this site. Yes I have worked out first card... but didn't get 15/51 . I now understand How it's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Greater than 3 and smaller than 8: Only 4,5,6,7 remain. So in total 16 of 52 cards satisfy the condition.

If I have drawn one card, and it satisfies the condition, only 15 out of 51 remaining cards satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Let A be the event - "Pick two cards such that both cards will be greater than 3 and less than 8"

The procedure of picking 2 cards from a standard deck of 52 can be broken down into 2 sequential tasks.

**Task 1**

Pick the first card from 52 such that this card is greater than 3 and less than 8. The possible choices are 4, 5, 6 and 7 for one suit, and so $4\times 4 = 16$ for the 4 suits. The probability is thus equal to $\frac{16}{52}$

**Task 2**

Pick the second card from $52-1 = 51$ left such that this card is greater than 3 and less than 8. Since we have already chosen the first card during the first task, there are only 15 possible ways of completing this task. The probability is hence $\frac{15}{51}$

By the **Product Rule**:

$$P(A) = \frac{16}{52}\times \frac{15}{51} =  \frac{20}{221}$$